# insert statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, jdbc

```
        String myquery="INSERT INTO likestatus values(?,?)";


        PreparedStatement st1=con.prepareStatement(myquery);
        st1.setString(1,Integer.toString(rid));
        st1.setString(2, id);
        st1.executeUpdate(myquery);
```

the error I am getting is

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '?,?)' at
>   line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your final line you have passed in the sql string again bypassing the prepared statement functionality. Just change the final line to this:

```
st1.executeUpdate();
```

PreparedStatement extends Statement so executeUpdate(String) is still available however you don't use it normally as the object knows has the sql, you use executeUpdate() instead.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you need to specify the concrete column names you provide values for:

```
INSERT INTO likestatus (column1, column2) values (?, ?)
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code:

```
st1.setString(2, id);
```

type of id is `string`? you need to make sure you are using the corresponding `setXXX` method corresponds to the `datatype`.